# How to remove multiple ROIs in the same general area on Fiji

Tags: image-segmentation, fiji

I am wondering if anyone knows how to delete multiple ROIs in the same general area of an image. I'm using Fiji.

I am looking for an easy way to delete all ROIs in a given area. For example, the multi-point selection tool has the ability to delete all points within a given selection. I would like to find a function like this but for ROIs.

I have many images like the one below (>100) with ROIs labelling cells. I only want ROIs to label cells in a certain region of the image (the barrel cortex) and would like to get rid of all other ROIs.

Would someone have an idea of how to write a macro to perform this function?

Any help would be greatly appreciation.

Thanks!

[image: 1]